# If statement doesn't properly evaluate in simple foreach loop

Tags: php, phalcon

I've come across a strange issue matching a simple condition within a foreach loop. I am using the PhalconPHP framework, however I don't think it is relevant to the problem.

The problem is that the variable `$var` is not properly evaluated in the if statement within my foreach loop. However when i manually overwrite the variable it does work correctly.

I don't understand what the difference is between the value **2** created by the output of $cookie->getValue(); and the **2** that I manually define?

```
    var_dump($var) // Outputs NULL

    if($cookie) {
        $var = $cookie->getValue();
    }

    var_dump($var) // Outputs string(32) "2"

    foreach($array as $row) {
        var_dump($var) // Outputs string(32) "2" string(32) "2" string(32) "2"
        var_dump($row['thing']); // Outputs string(1) "1" string(1) "2" string(1) "3"

        if($var == $row['thing']) { // Never evaluates as true
            echo 'hello world'; // Nothing
            $var2 = 'hello world';
        }
    }

    var_dump($var2); // Outputs NULL
```

If however I overwrite the variable manually, before the foreach loop, it does correctly evaluate.

```
    var_dump($var); // Outputs NULL

    if($cookie) {
        $var = $cookie->getValue();
    }

    var_dump($var); // Outputs string(32) "2"

    //OVERWRITE VAR
    $var = 2;

    foreach($array as $row) {
        var_dump($var); // Outputs int(2) int(2) int(2)
        var_dump($row['thing']); // Outputs string(1) "1" string(1) "2" string(1) "3"

        if($var == $row['thing']) { // Evaluates Correctly
            echo 'hello world'; // Outputs "hello world"
            $var2 = 'hello world';
        }
    }

    var_dump($var2); // Outputs string(11)"hello world"
```

Any tips on what I am doing wrong or how I can best debug this further?

Comment: `var_dump($var);` --- always prefer `var_dump` over `echo` for debugging

Comment: You might want to use $var = intval($cookie->getValue());

Comment: @zerkms Great tip, thanks, Looks like the function is outputting a string(32) "2". However isn't the double equals (==) meant to ignore type?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, re-read the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah user var_dump, it is always your fault , don't think that you have found PHP bug ( I always do )
before your foreach statement put

```
var_dump($var , $row['thing']);
echo "====\n";
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. `$var1 = string(32) "2"` and `$row['thing'] = string(1) "2"`. However this still doesn't explain why it's not correctly evaluating the condition. Correct me if I am wrong but doesn't double equals == try and ignore type???

Comment: It says that your `$var1` is a 32 character string. Can you please look at the page source when you get those var dumps and show us what `$var1` outputs?

Comment: Ok the problem was indeed that the string was 32 characters long with with a value of just 2? The function that generates this is a Phalcon function so I'll chase it up with them. The solution was of to use intval() to convert it back to an integer.